# How to show $ \Bbb Q（ζ_n,i）＝ \Bbb Q（ζ_N）$, where $ N＝LCM（n,4）$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, roots-of-unity

How to show 
$ \Bbb Q（ζ_n,i）＝ \Bbb Q（ζ_N）$, where $N＝LCM（n,4）$?

And what is the intuitive understanding of this equal ?
I Guess $i$ has period 4 has important meaning.

I tried a problem ' Is $\Bbb Q（sin2π/n）/\Bbb Q $ Galois ? 
And I reached this question .Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Another way is trying with  $\Bbb Q（ζ_n,i）＝ \Bbb Q（ζ_n+i)$ (primitive element).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, $\mathbb Q(\zeta_{n},\zeta_m) = \mathbb Q(\zeta_{lcm(n,m)})$. There are many ways to see this depending on what you know. One inclusion is clear since $\zeta_{lcm(n,m)}^{lcm(n,m)/n} = \zeta_n$ and similarly for $m$.

For the other direction, note that $\zeta_n\zeta_m = e^{2\pi i(1/n+1/m)}$ is a root of unity of order $lcm(n,m)$.

As for the original problem you started with (and you probably know this!), you can observe that since $\mathbb Q(\zeta_n,i)/\mathbb Q$ is Galois, any subextension has to be Galois (by Galois theory, this corresponds to the fact that all subgroups of abelian groups are normal!).

Comment: Thank you ! Sorry, but what is a definition of ζlcm（n,m）/n,lcm（n.m）　？

Comment: That is just the $lcm(n,m)$ root of unity raised to the power $lcm(n,m)/n = m/\gcd(n,m)$.